# CSS Basic Layout - 3 divs + 1 div inside another, centered

Tags: css, html, center

I got a problem that i just can't get my head around.
I want three different divs, filling the whole page (no scrollbars) and the middle div with another div centered horizontally and vertically inside of it.
I tried so much, but something is always destroying the layout.

So far, this is my code:

```
html, body {
background-image: url(images/bg_tile.gif);
background-repeat: repeat;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
resize:none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
height: 14%;
background-color: #09F;
top: 0px;
}

#body_con {
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
background-color: #0CF;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 6%;
background-color: #09F;
bottom: 0px;
}

#body_image {   
width: 90%;
height: 90%;
margin:0px auto;
background-color: white;
}
```

I know, somehow it's possible but i just can't get it to work.
Any ideas ?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/w774g/

Thank you,
Leo

Comment: Please show us the HTML.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Of course!

`<body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body_con">
         <div id="body_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
</body>`

Comment: @MaciejPraprocki

http://jsfiddle.net/w774g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the positions of the edges of an absolutely positioned div, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/w774g/1/

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 86%;
    background-color: #09F;
}

#body_con {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 14%;
    bottom: 6%;
    background-color: #0CF;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 94%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #09F;
}

#body_image { 
    position: absolute;  
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: nice one... it should be actually `5%` :)

Comment: Awesome, this solution is elegant and solved the problem !
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#body_con {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #0CF;
    /* added */
    position: relative;
}
#body_image {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color: white;
    /* added */
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/CyGfL/1/)